# how to converting sql to orm cakephp2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

So I have this query that I am trying to convert to cake ORM and I do not know how to go about it

```
SELECT users.id, users.email, users.phone, SUM(user_orders.quantity ) , SUM(user_orders.total_price )
FROM `users`
JOIN `user_orders` ON users.id = user_orders.user_id
WHERE users.role_id =2
AND user_orders.status =1
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY SUM( user_orders.quantity ) DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Users model:

```
$this->virtualFields = array(
    'sum_user_orders_quantity' => 'SUM(UserOrders.quantity)',
    'sum_user_orders_total_price' => 'SUM(UserOrders.total_price)',
);
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Users.id',
        'Users.email',
        'Users.phone',
        'UserOrders.sum_user_orders_quantity',
        'UserOrders.sum_user_orders_total_price',
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Users.id = UserOrders.user_id',
            ),
            'table' => 'user_orders',
            'alias' => 'UserOrders',
            'type' => 'join',
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Users.role_id' => '2',
        'UserOrders.status' => '1',
    ),
    'group' => array(
        'Users.id',
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'SUM(UserOrders.quantity)' => 'desc',
    ),
    'limit' => '200',
    'contain' => array(
        'UserOrders',
    ),
);
$data = $this->find('all', $options);
```

If you're new to using CakePHP 2.x, I recommend taking a look at [Dogmatic](http://dogmatic69.com/sql-to-cakephp-find-converter) to give you some ideas on converting SQL to CakePHP query syntax.

Comment: `'type' => 'join'` should be `'type' => 'INNER'`. Also, I don't think you need to contain `UserOrders`, this will fetch the `hasMany` relationship (provided it's declared and the class is called `UserOrders` and not `UserOrder` following CakePHP conventions. The rest seems correct.